# How do I assign separate font styles to the first row and first column of selected table in MS Word with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a macro to format selected tables in Word.

The macro utilizes Table styles. I also need to use font styles.

I am trying to assign the first row a specific font style, the first column a specific font style, and the rest of the table text another font style for a selected table.

I do not want to format all of the tables in the document at one time because occasionally there are tables that require different formatting.

The `Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Table Cell Center")` line covers the table text.
How do I assign separate font styles to the first row and first column?

```vb
Sub TableFormatRecording()
'
' Original TableFormat Macro Recording
'
'With Selection.Tables(1)
        .TopPadding = InchesToPoints(0)
        .BottomPadding = InchesToPoints(0)
        .LeftPadding = InchesToPoints(0.08)
        .RightPadding = InchesToPoints(0.08)
        .Spacing = 0
        .AllowPageBreaks = False
        .AllowAutoFit = False
    End With
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .Color = -587137025
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .Color = -587137025
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .Color = -587137025
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .Color = -587137025
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .Color = -587137025
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderVertical)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .Color = -587137025
        End With
        .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders.Shadow = False
    End With
    With Options
        .DefaultBorderLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .DefaultBorderLineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .DefaultBorderColor = -587137025
    End With
    Selection.Tables(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    Selection.Tables(1).PreferredWidth = 100
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = False
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows.HeadingFormat = True
    Selection.Tables(1).Style = "G Table Style"
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Table Cell Center")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is your code applying all that formatting to the table and then applying a table style? Your table style should include all that formatting, that’s what table styles are for.

If applying paragraph or character styles to a table you start by applying the style that you require for the body of the table, then the first column, lastly the first row (unless the top left cell is required in the same format as the rest of the column).

To apply a style to the body of the table:

```
Selection.Tables(1).Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleName")
```

To apply a style to the first row:

```
Selection.Tables(1).Rows.First.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleName")
```

To apply a style to the first column:

```
Selection.Tables(1).Columns.First.Select
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleName")
```

NOTE: this is one of the few instances where using `Select` is justified, because  a table column does not have a `Range` property. The alternative is to loop through all the cells of the column applying the style to each cell.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear answer! This is exactly what I've been trying to find.
The reason there's so much code is because I recorded it in order to see the various code for the different formatting. I'm still trying to learn about VBA.

For reasons I haven't been able to yet determine, when I apply the table style, the row height doesn't adjust the way I need it to and like it does when font styles are applied. I've checked the various settings in the table style but can't figure it out.

Comment: @Durban - Table styles sit at the bottom of the style hierarchy. For the text formatting they apply to work correctly the table the style is applied to must be formatted with a style that represents the document defaults, Normal in an unedited template. Document defaults are set in the Set Defaults tab of the Manage Styles dialog, found at the bottom of the Styles Pane.

Answer (score 0):

Table styles in Word allow customizing the table appearance in a centralized way. It is best to define the base formatting through a table style rather than individually.

You can still modify the font styling of the first row and first column separately from the table style or with VBA code. However, note that manipulating tables through VBA in Word is different than Excel.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim oTab As Table, c As Cell
    Set oTab = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    oTab.Columns.First.Select
    With Selection.Range
        .Bold = True
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
    End With
    With oTab.Rows.First.Range
        .Bold = True
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Although I have the table style set exactly how I want it, it doesn't adjust the row height when applied the way it does when the font styles are specified. I could easily be missing something as to why that's not happening, but I haven't found a reason for it yet when I look through the various table properties and font and paragraph settings.